# sqlite update works only once at first then fails

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I've got a method that is supposed to update a row in a table
but it only works once and then when I want to update the second row or other rows it doesn't work...

here's the update method:

```
@Override
public boolean updateRelayItemStatus(int deviceId, String itemDefaultName, int status) {
    LogClass.logD("start updating '"+itemDefaultName+"'");

    SQLiteDatabase sql = db.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Database.R_STATUS, status);


    long responseId = sql.update(Database.TABLE_RELAYS, contentValues, Database.R_ID + " =? AND " + Database.R_DEFAULT_NAME + " =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(deviceId), itemDefaultName});

    sql.close();
    LogClass.logD("update relay row for '" + itemDefaultName + "' " +
            " -  '"+deviceId+"' " +
            " -  '"+status+"'  =======   " + (responseId > 0 ? "succeed" : "failed"));
    return responseId > 0;
}
```

and this is the table:

```
private final String CREATE_RELAYS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RELAYS + "("
            + R_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + R_DEVICE_ID + " TEXT, "
            + R_DEFAULT_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + R_CUSTOM_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + R_ICON + " INTEGER,"
            + R_TIME + " INTEGER,"
            + R_STATUS + " INTEGER);";
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in Logcat when the `update()` fails?

Comment: @MichaelDodd no nothing, but but the response variable is 0 and no update happens

Comment: You shouldn't need `id=? AND default_name=?` as id should uniquely identify a row (i.e you should just need id=?). Perhaps they are not in sync. I'd suggest getting row from the table, by id and adding columns from to log to compare id and default_name.

Comment: ohhh  i was using the wrong id column.. thanks for mentioning that :D @MikeT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... i have two Id in my table
one of them is simply the unique Id and the other is id of device from another table and for updating i need device id but I had used the other id that's what was causing the problem